# Difference in function declaration C

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

Is there difference in C if I declare function like this:

```
Type * AK_init_observer();
```

and like this:

```
Type* *AK_init_observer();
```

Comment: Yeah, the second one returns a double pointer (`Type**`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

- In the first case, `AK_init_observer` returns a pointer to `Type` (`Type *`).
- In the second case, `AK_init_observer` returns a pointer to pointer to `Type` (`Type **`).

Since spaces don't matter here, the two declarations are equivalent to:

```
Type *AK_init_observer();
```

and:

```
Type **AK_init_observer();
```

### References

> #### C11 (n1570), § 5.1.1.1 Program structure
>
> 7) White-space characters separating tokens are no longer significant.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the return types are different. The first returns a pointer to `Type`, whereas the second returns a pointer to pointer to `Type`.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to understand with a well-known type, say `int`, instead of `Type`:

```
int *f1();
```

Returns a pointer to the int. You can follow the pointer and find the int:

```
int *p = f1();
printf("%d\n", *p);
```

However:

```
int **f2();
```

Returns a pointer, which points to another pointer, which points to the int:

```
int **p1 = f2();
int *p2 = *p1;
printf("%d\n", *p2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on the second one you're returning a pointer to a pointer. For example:

```
char *function();             // Returns a pointer to a char - or a 'string'


char **function();            // Returns an array of strings
```

Comment: The difference between strings and character pointers is very tricky, which makes this answer very confusing.

Comment: Apart from the fact it has nothing to do with it, a string is typically a `char *`.

Comment: Ooh I see now, I typed my comments wrong. Man that's what I get for doing stuff in a hurry. I've edited my answer. Thank you so much guys